# jQuery match regex

Tags: jquery, regex

```
var playerClass = $(this).parent().attr('class')
```

Question about only selecting a specific class from the dom.

What can I add to this line to only select the class that has a class of player-1, player-2, basically anything with a prefix of player- followed by a number?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I couldn't tell exactly what you were asking with your question, so here are four possibilities.  Hopefully one of these matches what you intended to ask or you can slightly modify one of them to fit.

To select all input items with a class of `player-xx` where `xx` is a number, you can do this:

```
var playerClass = $('input[class^="player-"]').filter(function() {
    return((" " + this.className + " ").match(/\splayer-\d+\s/) != null);
});
```

The first jQuery selector gets any class name that starts with `"player-"`.  The filter then eliminates any items that aren't also `"player-nn"`.

If you're only trying to examine whether one particular classname contains `player-nn`, then you can do that like this:

```
if ((" " + $(this).parent().attr('class') + " ").match(/\splayer-\d+\s/) != null) {
    // the parent has player-nn as a class
}
```

If you just want to get the matching class on the parent, you can do that with this:

```
var matches = (" " + $(this).parent().attr('class') + " ").match(/\s(player-\d+)\s/);
if (matches) {
    playerClass = matches[1];
}
```

If you're trying to actually get the number after the `player-`, you can do that like this:

```
var matches = (" " + $(this).parent().attr('class') + " ").match(/\splayer-(\d+)\s/);
if (matches) {
    playerNum = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
}
```

Note: All of these examples use a trick (which I learned from jQuery) that if you add a space onto the beginning and end of the overall classname, then you can look for a given classname with a regex by looking for your particular classname surround on both sides by whitespace.  This makes sure you don't match a part of a longer classname and only match whole classnames.  jQuery uses this trick in it's `.hasClass()` implementation.

Comment: I have one additional request that you may be able to provide.. How would I be able to provide an additional request to see if it also matches a class "not-pictured"

here is the code I am currently using now..

var playerClass = $(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\bplayer-\S+/g)

Comment: @Greg - if you just want to add the `not-pictured` to the same regex, you can do that like this:  `.match(/\bplayer-\S+|not-pictured/g)`.  If that's not what you wanted, then I don't understand your new question so please clarify.

Comment: That is working fine, although it is returning it comma separated...
player-3, not-pictured
Is there a way to just get "player-3 not-pictured"

Comment: @Greg - you could test the results to make sure it wasn't null and then use `.join(" ")` on the match array.  See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nsH2Z/

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you need:

```
var playerClass = $(this).parent().attr('class').match(/player-\d+/);
```

Answer (score 2):

To select all `input` elements that have a class name starting with "player-", you could use this:

```
var playerClass = $('input[class^="player-"]');
```

The "starts-with" selector is described here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

This will not ensure that "player-" is immediately followed by a digit though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery regex selector:

- http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/